# When selecting possible duplicates, can the popup dialog be made so it doesn't block the question?

Tags: bug

The modal dialog that comes up when you flag something for moderator attention covers the question frame, and is not moveable. This is inconvenient when you're trying to cut/paste/refer to one of the questions mentioned as a possible duplicate into the frame--you have to open a second window.

(Obviously if the software guesses the right duplicate to show you, this isn't a problem, but that doesn't always happen.)

Comment: Movable modals would be awesome. All modals on the network have this issue since they can't be moved, it's just most noticeable with the dupe one.

Comment: So how do we elevate this request? There are a ton of JS libraries out there to do just this.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is the place for general network feature requests if it doesn't get any attention here.

Comment: Alright; I asked it there.